# PHP / Wordpress - submenus

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on Wordpress recently and gnaw on the display of sub-menus.
I have a problem using this code here.

```
<div id="site-header-menu" class="site-header-menu">
    <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) : ?>

        <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'primary',
                'menu_class'     => 'nav navbar-nav',
            ) );
        ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'social' ) ) : ?>

        <nav id="social-navigation" class="social-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="<?php _e( 'Social Links Menu', 'twentysixteen' ); ?>">
            <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location' => 'social',
                    'menu_class'     => 'social-links-menu',
                    'depth'          => 1,
                    'link_before'    => '<span class="screen-reader-text">',
                    'link_after'     => '</span>',
                ) );
            ?>
```

**My submenus are displayed like this:**

[image]

1. How can i edit the class of the submenus?
2. Do i have any mistake so they appear like that?

Can you please help me out fix them. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What's the problem? Doesn't look like the theme you're using has any styling defined for sub-menus.